# umap tilelayer on embedded iframe not showing up on mobile devices

Tags: iframe, leaflet, openstreetmap, tile

I have created a map using [umap](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/) and embedded it on a [website](https://firmen.wiki/startseite.html) using the built-in iframe option. It works totally fine on desktop but the tile layer doesn't show up on mobile -- instead, the background is just grey. It does show up if it's manually selected through the menu by the user.

I have tried:

- different browsers/devices
- using a different tile theme
- different screen resolutions in the dev console (all normal, just an issue on actual phones)
- different iframe sizes and absolute/relative values
- enabling/disabling scroll wheel zoom

**current iframe code on the website:**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/meinfirmenwiki_426663?scaleControl=true&miniMap=false&zoomControl=true&allowEdit=false&moreControl=false&searchControl=null&tilelayersControl=null&embedControl=null&datalayersControl=expanded&onLoadPanel=none&captionBar=false&fullscreenControl=true"></iframe>
```

Edit: it's the same when checking the map on the [umap website](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/meinfirmenwiki_426663#8/46.886/8.278)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configured [tile layer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer) doesn't support "retina tiles". These tiles are used for displays with a high DPI. These are commonly found on smartphones and on large desktop screens.

The difference between these two is the tile layer URL. In your configuration a "standard" tile is retrieved for example via

https://a.forte.tiles.quaidorsay.fr/en/8/137/91.png

while a "retina tile" is retrieved via

https://a.forte.tiles.quaidorsay.fr/en@2x/8/137/91.png

Note the `@2x`. The latter URL doesn't exist, though. This means you either have to switch to a tile server supporting retina tiles or you have to disable retina tiles for your map.

To disable retina tiles you have to remove the `{r}` placeholder from your tile URL. Replace

`https://{s}.forte.tiles.quaidorsay.fr/en{r}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

with

`https://{s}.forte.tiles.quaidorsay.fr/en/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`